# Symfony Forms with 2 databases

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpstorm

I could not really find my specific case on the internet and therefore decided on writing my own question.

I have a form to create a Member object. This member object has a reference to an application object. Both are saved in 2 different databases.

Creating a Member object is no issue only when I edit and fill out the form, do I encounter an error ->

> Entity of type "Application"
>   passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to
>   persist it in the entity manager

Here is my Form Code

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('membberName', null, array('label' => false))
        ->add('memberDescription', TextareaType::class, array('label' => false))
        ->add('memberVisible', null, array('label' => false))
        ->add('memberApp', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'class' => Application::class,
            'choice_label' => function (Application $application) {
                return sprintf('(%d) %s', $application->getAppId(), $application->getAppurlUrl());
            },
            'choices' => $this->applicationRepository->getAll(),

        ])
        ->add('Save', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'create-button']
        ]);

}
```

I found a lot of cases about this issue but none of them could help me.
I only encounter this issue if I load an entity that is related to another one outside their own database.

To summarize: calling the create view page and pressing on submit works.
Calling the edit view causes the above mentioned issue.

Do I have to define or configure anything so my form can load correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up custom `em` for your entity form field `memberApp` in options to your second database entity manager.

like described in docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em

> em type: string | Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager default:
>   the default entity manager
>
> If specified, this entity manager will be used to load the choices
>   instead of the default entity manager.

Another way, probably would be to set `['mapped' => false]` for this field and handling flush manually with correct database's em in controller or service

Comment: Hi I created custom repositories with ems. In Service file i declare the specific repositories to use a different database. Therefore for the most part I can work with 2 different databases. It only fails when I work with forms that contain entities in both databases. If I use mapped, then I do not receive the error message anymore but when loading the form the field for memberApp is empty. Maybe I misunderstood you? Could you further elaborate your first answer?

Comment: I followed your second approach set it to falsed and tried to do the persist and flush manually. When I flush the data after manually setting the memberApp, i Receive an undefined index error... Any idea?